# Having catkin_make trouble in ros kinetic android tutorials

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, maven-2, ros, catkin

First of all the english is not my First language so sorry for that any problems in grammar things

Anyway I have trouble working on [android/Tutorials/kinetic/Installation](http://wiki.ros.org/android/Tutorials/kinetic/Installation%20-%20ROS%20Development%20Environment)  - ROS Development Environment  parts 3.1 last line 'catkin_make'

I'm currently working on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and ros kinetic openjdk-8

when I'm tried to catkin_make the project, the console shows

```
> > 
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android_core'.
Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2.
Required by:
project :
Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2.
Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.2/gradle-3.5.2.pom'.
Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.2/gradle-3.5.2.pom'.
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

> >
```

In this situation I have decided to download gradle-3.5.2.pom directly and just put that in to
~/android_core/src/android_core and change directions in buildscript.gradle(which is include rootProject.buildscript) links -> "gradle-3.5.2.pom"

after that I clean android_core projects and trying to rebuild it

and this happen

```
script '/home/user/android_core/src/android_core/gradle-3.5.2.pom': 1: unexpected token: < @ line 1, column 1.
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     ^
  
  1 error
```

this situation takes my whole weekend if you have any ideas to resolve this problem please let me know as soon as possible

thanks

*I already trying to another android-gradle versions

Comment: What about: `unable to find valid certification path to requested target`??

Comment: Thanks for your answering, however I already trying to fix PKIX errors through adding dl.google.com certification to the java, but it doesn't show any changes in errors sadly